# cannot resolve method's SparkSession(),the version of dependency what I used is 2.4.3

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to create a basic SparkSession。but my IDEA warns me that cannot resolve symbol 'SparkSession', and I also can't find org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.
the code below is what I find in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html

I try some version of dependency including 2.3.4、2.1.1、2.0.2、2.3.0, and all is a failure.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
SparkSession spark = SparkSession()
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
            .getOrCreate();
```

there is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you add the dependencies for your project?

Comment: I am sorry ,I use apache maven.I have edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just should add the dependency for Spark SQL:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```